# Notation for the sets of locally Lipschitz continuous and differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Are there any standard notation for denoting the following sets?

- the set of locally Lipschitz continuous functions, $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$;
- the set of differentiable functions, $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Usually $C^{0,1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^m)$ for the first one. I don't know of a standard notation for the second.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff

Comment: In Riemannian geometry, the set of differentiable functions of class k ranging from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $ \mathbb{R}^m$ is denoted by $C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$.

Comment: @Eduardo Maza Can you please explain? Is it the same as the k-times continuously differentiable functions?

Comment: @Mehran, yes its the same.